# A better way to pass IDs

Tags: symfony

I have a problem - or a concern - about my app. Experience taught me, that leaving ANY possible way to mainpulate my code is very, very bad. So now, I have a form which adds user's opinion. It has

- a text field `textarea`
- a user_id field `input type="hidden"`
- a game_id field  `input type="hidden"`

Now what I am afraid of, is that user might want to look at the code and find those fields. Many browsers allow to manipulate HTML (we can change classes, etc from Chrome). So changing `value="1"` to `value="2"` won't be a problem to them.

My question is - what are the best practics in Symfony2 to avoid such problems and risks?

Comment: As always: Validation on server side?

Comment: I am looking for something more like removing those `hidden` fields entirely and having Symfony2 send IDs without displaying them. With user it is easy, but now with other IDs.

Comment: As long as you don't want your users to forbid using tabs there is no other way than sending a kind of status with the form-request. You can map the IDs against a dynamically generated key and use this within your form, but I must say, that I don't know, whats the big deal? Just validate, wether or not the IDs are valid in the given context (identical to how you would do it, when they werent hidden-inputs, but text-inputs)

Comment: So how can I do this? I mean, if user changes from `value="1"` to `value="2"`, it still would be valid, since both games with id `1` and `2` are in the database. I moved from this issue to what I described, because I coudn't find any solution for validating referrer's id.

Comment: The overall questions are always the same: Is the user allowed to do "X"? And are the values given to do "X" valid? So for example if somebody changes the game-id manually it to "2", he either sees an error (because he isn't allowed to post to "2"), or he posts his opinion to game "2" instead. But he could have opened the form for game "2" anway, so what is the win from the attackers point of view? He did something, that he was allowed to do anyway.

Comment: "or he posts his opinion to game "2" like how it would be, when you opened the form for game "2" (but more complicated)" - and that I want to avoid. But I don't know how to check if user submitted that id that he should. Since I have different controller for displaying game (and form) and different for recieving form data, I can't just get id from `game` object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the user and game id from your form you could just grab them in your controller, which is handling the post anyways and process both values right there.

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$userId = $user->getId();
$gameId = $user->getGame()->getId();
```

Is a possible way of getting the current needed values (depending on where your game id comes from of course)

Edit:

If the user is associated with more than one game you could hand over the gameId like you did inititally and cast it via dependecy injection directly to a game class:

```
public function exampleAction(Game $gameId) {
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    if($user->getGames()->contains($gameId) {
     return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess a user may be associated with more than one game? Also I guess it could be possible, that a user may write a comment about a game, that he is not directly associated with.

Comment: I that case you can hand the id over a hidden field like he initially did and check if the user is associated with that game.

Comment: User doesn't have to be assosiated with a game, he can just write an opinion like "i played it at my friends house and..." or so. So no user-game relations here. But even if they were, user can be associated to a lot of games, like KingCrunch said.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but like I said, even if user want to add an opinion, he can be related to many games, so he can change id from `1` to `2` and stil pass the validation.

Comment: So you are just afraid of people spoofing the user id? Then just use the current user, like described in my first code example.

Comment: As @Schwierig said, your best bet is to move the user out of the form and instead get it from the session. I have several comment pages like this, generally the user gets set after validation but before I persist the object.